# Wanting to Install Ubuntu, currently have Windows, don't want to lose files

Tags: system-installation

I was going through the Windows Installer page and it's made very simple. I'm just wondering if I'll lose my files if I do that. I had Ubuntu, loved it, got a new laptop, and should've installed Ubuntu then but didn't. I don't have any external storage media currently available to me, but if I can install Ubuntu without losing my files I'll go ahead and do that.
Help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Try Ubuntu with a liveCD or liveUSB. To see if it works with your laptop. because sometimes you may end up with a black screen.

Second thing, Try to back up your data. I know you don't have any external storage. But try to find one. To tell you the truth I don't back up my data. Even when I installed Ubuntu for the first time. Because the installation process is really simple. all you have to do is to click on "Install alongside windows" option and it will automatically adjust it for you.

Now, if you want to select the "advanced option". At that time you should really consider backing up your data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a CD or are you installing from wubi.exe by copying the files over from the .iso / disc image onto a folder?

I was able to just run wubi.exe while Windows 7 was still running by taking all the install files off of the disc image. It made a .disk file in my Windows folder, set up a boot option and restarted perfectly. All my Windows files were perfectly fine.
I don't know what to add for someone using a CD though.

Comment: You basically just spoke Japanese to me, my friend, haha!
I'm using the wubi download. I'm not sure how to do the rest of the stuff you just mentioned.

Comment: wubi should work completely fine for you, it's made to make this easy. When you start your computer a Windows Boot Manager selection screen will pop up and ask you if you want to start Windows or Ubuntu. Your windows files will show up as a folder called Host inside a device/drive/partition named FILESYSTEM when you look for them through Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that I would recommend:

You can install Ubuntu through WUBI -

> Install the installer with the CD in Windows(wubi.exe) then finish the
>   installation with a reboot(leaving the CD in the tray)
>
> This allows you to install Ubuntu to where it is easily uninstalled in windows. This also
>   has the lowest risk of you losing your data.

You can install alongside Windows -

> Boot from Live CD/USB. When installing, click the option "Install alongside Windows". This should not install over your existing data and prevents a low risk of losing your data

How to later retrieve your files:

WUBI:
In File Browser, goto /host/

Alongside Windows: The partition should show up in the side of the file browser. e.g. Mine says "Acer"

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method is wubi ubuntu.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer Just click "Get the installer" and it should start downloading. After you download, save; it asks you you enter username, password, and then tells you to restart the computer. Once you restart, ubuntu automatically starts. Then, shut down the computer and when you start it, there are two options: windows, AND ubuntu. You are ready to go. This is the method that I followed and successfully downloaded ubuntu.

It's a great thing as you have windows and you have ubuntu (without altering anything in your windows).